# do direct payment api: no response from paypal sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using the codeigniter library from angelleye's library (http://www.angelleye.com/download-codeigniter-php-library-for-paypal-payments-pro/).
For a few days, it worked smoothly without any errors. Today when I tested it I got no response from paypal.

I contacted the author(Andrew), and he said that the paypal sandbox server is timing out with the do direct payment.
My question is, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal sandbox does that at times, and unfortunately there's nothing we can do about it but wait on PayPal to get things working smoothly.

The sandbox has been running great for awhile now, but it seems that with many of the recent changes they're making (they're working on a new sandbox, and they're pushing PayFlow more than DirectPayment now) the DirectPayment API on the sandbox has been suffering.

In fact, just now I was about to respond and let you know that last time I tried it was working fine.  I went to test it and sure enough, it timed out again.  I tried again, though, and it worked fine.  So unfortunately, the sandbox is just pretty hit and miss these days with DirectPayment.

You could always switch to PayFlow, which is what they're pushing these days, and my library supports it now if you have the latest version.